# Is there a chrome and safari version for -moz-inline-stack

Tags: css

Is there a version of

```
-moz-inline-stack
```

for chrome and safari?

something along the lines of

```
  display: -webkit-inline-stack;  
  display: -ms-inline-stack;
  display: -o-inline-stack;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Chrome and Safari just use `display: inline-block;`

Here is some cross-browser inline block css:

```
.my-element {
        display: -moz-inline-stack;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
}
```

Old article with more explanation [here](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/).